# Why does my htaccess code not work?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Could you please explain why my .htaccess code does not work? Whatever the right code is, I'm trying to better understand URL Rewriting and Redirecting and **I would appreciate a more verbose/detailed explanation of** all syntax and code. Most answers on SO simply state the answer with very little explanation.

```
# Hypertext Access Directives by Govind Rai

# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

###############last two directives that don't work#######################

# hide .html extension govie v1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html$
RewriteRule ^/[^.]+\.html$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]

#internal redirect to the right .html file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^/([^.]+)$ /$1.html [L]
```

I want to understand why the last two rules are not working. When i access a url without the `.html` extension I get a 404 page not found error, and a url with extension does not rewrite itself without an extension. I've posted the entire file incase there are conflicting rules.

Comment: To get any help you will need to tell us more details: what do you actually mean by "are not working"? Consider that we cannot look over your shoulders... It rewriting doing something wrong? You get an error? Nothing happens? The universe implodes? You cannot _guess_ what is happening on your side...

Comment: @arkascha my bad. updating question. Nothing happens.

Comment: Apart from that a hint: to understand how the tool you are using is working in details you should start reading documentations. The apache documentation about the rewriting module is of excellent quality and comes with really good examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for that, I had a very hard time reading the actual apache documentation and I've been reading some good resources that have led me so far. I even have code that works, but I wanted to write my own code to really perfect my understand..have been failing pretty badly.

Comment: Sure, sometimes we all need help. Asking a direct, specific question often get's better answers then something along the line "why does this not work". But maybe my answer below _did_ help a bit :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html$
```

That condition will never succeed because example value of `%{THE_REQUEST}` is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`. It represents the raw HTTP request as received by Apache.

You can use these rules to fix your issue:

```
RewriteEngine On

## add www and turn on https in same rule

# if HOST name doesn't start with www. - OR
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
# if HTTPS is off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# *capture* hostname part after www in %1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
# redirect with https://www.%1/... to always apply https and www
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

## hide .html extension
# if original request is ending with .html then capture part before .html in %1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
# and redirect to %1 (part without .html)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

# internally add .html if there a matching .html file in your web root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: I see. In your answer, could you also explain the `%1%` syntax? I've never seen that before, I've only seen the `$1`. What is the difference? Also what is the REQUEST_URI returning, since i'm assuming its different from THE_REQUEST? Just looking for a further verbose answer! Thanks for your help!

Comment: also, in the first three conditions, does the `[or]` mean mean 1 or (2 & 3) or (1 or 2) & 3?

Comment: Also, if you already check whether the URL doesn' t start with `www.` or if the URL doesn't specify `https`, why do you check the third condition? What is it checking? thank you!

Comment: I will write some comments in answer for 1st rule but meanwhile you should test the code and let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: Thank you anubhava. That works. So basically from the examples it seems you can use either % or $ to reference a capture group? So in the first rule could you have done `...www.$1%{REQUEST_URI}...` Also say I had a subdomain, blog.hostname.com, these rules would add a www in front as well correct?

Comment: No `$1, $2 ..` are captured value from `RewriteRule` and `%1, %2` etc are captured values from `RewriteCond`. Yes these rules will add `www` for `blog.hostname.com` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue most likely is a pretty simple one: when using rewrite rules inside `.htaccess` style files the request path is relative, so does *not* insist on a leading slash. That means you have to modify your rules patterns slightly:

```
#enable rewriting
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap /

#internal redirect to the right .html file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.html$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^.]+)$ /$1.html [END]

# hide .html extension govie v1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^.]+)\.html$ /$1 [NC,R=301,END]
```

Instead of completely removing that leading slash I personally like the idea of adding a question mark, so making them optional. This allows to use the same rules inside the http servers host configuration without modification.

I also added the well known twin rules to check if the request does not address a physically existing file or folder. This typically is desired, but you obviously have to decide yourself.

---

A general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers real host configuration. These `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, they are hard to debug and really slow down the server, often without reason. They are only provided for situations where you do *not* have access to that configuration (read: really cheap hosting providers) or if your application needs to write its own rewriting rules (an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Ah, I read up on `THE_REQUEST`, `REQUEST_URI` and `REQUEST_FILENAME`. However, I'm pretty unclear on those topics and will reread those sections in the apache documentation. Still you've  shed some significant light! The current code did solve half the issue! However, it's still not rewriting the URL however...

Comment: @GovindRai Once more the same questions: what do you mean by "not rewriting the URL"? What _exactly_ do you mean by "rewriting" here? What URL?

Comment: Aw man.. sorry for being unclear. If I navigate to `host.com/about.html`, it should rewrite url to `host.com/about`, hence my two rules.

Comment: Hm, I added a slightly modified version, have a try with that. Remember that you have to make sure that your browser does not display a cached version of the response. So clear your browsers cache before retrying and make a "deep reload" instead of just reloading.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not stripping the extension.

Comment: @GovindRai Oops, sorry for that, forgot the brackets in that rewrite rule. Have another try with the updated rule set please.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still the same behavior.

Comment: Ok, I don't see any flaw left, so most likely this is a question of you being in a different situation than what I expect. I suggest you turn on rewrite logging and start monitoring an incoming request. Rewrite logging allows you to see what exactly is going on inside your rewrite engine. So what patterns are applied and what is done. That usually allows to gain a deeper insight. Rewrite logging is documented.

Comment: I'll see what can be done. I have godaddy :D. Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: Oh, I see, with such a hosting provider you most likely will not be able to use rewrite logging. That is not good... Let me just mention caching once more, are you _really_ sure you handled that? Next have a try placing a definite syntax error right before that rule you are working on. Do you _really_ get an immediate error which proves those lines are considered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128033/discussion-between-arkascha-and-govind-rai).

Answer (score 0):

`${THE_REQUEST}` contains The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`) so it will never match `\.html$` (since it never ends with `.html`). Perhaps you can try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```